'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4492: character maps to <undefined> error in Langchain directory loader for csv files
I am using Langchain Directory Loader to read multiple csv files.Below is the code:
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
csv_loader_kwargs = {"autodetect_encoding": True}
loader = DirectoryLoader(r'\path',glob="**/*.csv",loader_kwargs=csv_loader_kwargs)
docs=loader.load()

I am getting different error for two csv files:
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4492: character maps to 
&
All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
I tried using other python library like panda to read csv file with encoding parameter & I was able to read these files.But with langchain it failed.I tried adding a custom csv loader. Still no luck:
from langchain.document_loaders.csv_loader import CSVLoader
from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader

class CustomCSVLoader(CSVLoader):
    def load(self):
        # Use the working open logic
        with open(self.file_path, encoding="utf-8") as f:
            content = f.read()
        # Parse the content using the parent class logic
        return self._parse(content)

loader = DirectoryLoader(
    r'C:\path',
    glob="**/*.csv",
    loader_cls=CustomCSVLoader
)
docs = loader.load()type here

